# using lstat() on directories and getting incorrect answers

Tags: c, unix, stat

Im currently trying to build a program that gives the same output as **du -s** does. However i have found myself with a bug that i can't understand. My program will give me 8 less than the correct answer, for very large directories the answer also differ but then it's by more. For smaller directories it always gives me 8 less, no mather how many directories there is inside a directories etc.

My first thought was that i was not adding the size of the actuall directories disc usage and therefore fell short on the answer but that was not the issue. I also thought that i maybe generate corrupt paths for when i want to check a file inside of directory but then i would get a error printed since the file wouldn't be able to stat().

The following code is how i add upp the size for the files/directories, will **st_blocks** not give the correct size for directories? (i then divide this answer by 2)

```
        struct stat sb;
             if(lstat(file, &sb) == -1){
             perror(file);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *size += sb.st_blocks;
```

The basics of the rekursion i use to go trough is:

```
   while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")){
            continue;
        }
        else if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR){
            char path[1024];
            generate_path(path, dir_name, entry->d_name);
            traverse_dir(path, total_size);
            get_size_from_dir(path, total_size);

        }
        else{
            char path[1024];
            generate_path(path, dir_name, entry->d_name);
            get_size_from_single_file(path, total_size);
        }
    }
```

Where i get the size of the orignal directory outside of this funtion. Is it wrong for me to use st_blocks? I have tried using st_size but then i don't get close to the correct answer since it says that all my files has the size of 4096. Im new to this and don't have enough deep knowledge of how lstat works since it's my first time using it, i have read trough the manual but don't really understand what i do wrong. Could anyone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Needs a [mcve], not a snippet and some pseudocode.

Comment: it is difficult to understand your pseudo code, what difference between "path to next dir" and "new path" ? between "path for file" and "new path" ? The return value of *readdir* is commonly shared so you have to use the values of a given call of *readdir* **before** to call again *readdir*. `Where i get the size of the orignal directory outside of this funtion` : what function ? do you use valid data then ? Do you give additional options to *du* ? is to use option `--block-size=512` give the same result as your program without the `then divide this answer by 2` ? A 'K' can be 1000 or 1024

Comment: @Shawn Hope the edit, was easier to understand

Comment: to not have a dir (e.g. 'else') does not mean you have a file, do you have symbolic links for instance ?

Comment: @bruno thanks for your comment, i changed out the psuedo code to an actuall code snippet. I did not fully understand what you ment with use the values of the readdir, with the code snippet does it still look like i don't use that. The function is the same as get_size_from_dir(), only that it's called from a diffrent location since the logic did not work for me when putting it into the traverse function. The generate_path() simple adds a '/' between the dir and the file/dir.

Comment: ok so `dir_name` is not only the name but the pathname of the dir. again do you have links in your dir(s) ?

Comment: @bruno Correct the dir_name is sent in with the function, so when it's first called it will only be the directory name but when recalled the dir_name will then be the pathname

Comment: @bruno yes there can be links, or to clearify the program should work with symbolic links in the directorys. I do not have full knowledge of what they mean more than that they contain refrence to another file or dir

Comment: and again if you force the block size to be 1024b or 512b for *du* e.g. `du -s --block-size=1024 the-dir` do you have the same result as your program ? Your program in a way consider 1K is 1024 but perhaps by default your *du* counts with 1K is 1000 ? To divide by 1024 gives a value less than to divide by 1000

Comment: @bruno Yes sorry just tried it out, i get the same results even if i force it

Comment: can you give the full program to check you do not have undefined behavior and/or did you run your program through *valgrind* ? How is if you apply your program on a dir having only one file ? You say "unix", is MacOS X ?

Comment: This is *still* not a [mre]

Comment: @bruno I have no issue giving it to you to see if u can see any flaws but rather not put it out on stack since it's a school project, and need to learn this. I run it constatly on valgrind w/o any errors. That gives me the same result. I run it on the schools computer that uses some sort of linux system unsure which to be honest.

Comment: I just understand your problem => see answer

Comment: `d_type` is only supported on Linux, and, even there, not on all filesystems. Treat it only as a hint. But since you already `lstat(2)` all the files, you gain nothing by using `d_type` at all, you only make your code brittle and unportable.

Comment: Since it's a school project, better take my advice and do not use `d_type` -- it may affect your grade ;-) Simply `lstat(2)` any directory entry, add its `sb.st_blocks`, and `if(S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)))` then recurse into it.

Comment: @user431397 Thanks for your answer! I will definietly do then, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

warning :

- on an empty directory *du* returns 4, your program will return 0 (no files)
- on a dir without file but containing an empty dir `du -s` returns 8 (4+4) and your program will return 0 (no files)
- etc

so *du* returns not only the size needed by the files but also by the dir(s), but your program only consider the files => your program computes less than *du*

Comment: Thanks again for your time, this was exactly the knowledge i lacked and needed. Will try to implement this!

Comment: @forsb I didn't know *du* not only counts the files, note *4* is probably more in case there are lof of files/sub-dir in a dir

Comment: Just implemented a new solution with the information you gave me in mind and it now counts correctly even for very large directories! Thanks again much appreciated!